# Hide thumbnail for specific product categories in WooCommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, thumbnails, cart

I'm trying to hide the image in the WooCommerce Cart for certain categories. I found that adding this code removes all thumbnails from the Cart:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', '__return_false' );
```

I'm trying (and failing), to only remove this for certain categories, using the following code.

```php
function WooCartImage($woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail) {
if ( is_product_category(63) ) {
    $woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail = '__return_false';
}

return $woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'WooCartImage' );
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this and if anyone has a hint, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` filter hook contains 3 arguments,
the 2nd is `$cart_item`, so you can use `$cart_item['product_id']` in combination with [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail( $product_image, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $categories = array( 63, 15, 'categorie-1' );
    
    // Has term (product category)
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $product_image = '';
    }
    
    return $product_image;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @AlphaPixa Thanks for accepting my answer. However, know that you also have the option to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) this answer. Also see: [How can I upvote answers and comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400) Thanks in advance! With best regards